# Removed metho=True from functional field

Tags: odoo

Why **method=True** argument removed from functional field of new openerp?

Answer (score 3):

Yes `fields.function()` does not take a "method" parameter anymore[1]. It
was useless and every field was passing method=True. It is possible to
pass a normal function too, it simply needs to have the proper signature

---

[1] Server rev 3495 revid
odo@openerp.com-20110701232328-flgxulxva70vnyxr and addons rev 4844
revid odo@openerp.com-20110701234124-a61zl0idvdfz3hyb

Answer (score 0):

**method=True** argument is not removed from openERP-7. You can check it in addons.

You can find it [account.py](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openerp/openobject-addons/7.0/view/head:/account/account_cash_statement.py) at line: 182-183